# Why can't I load Images?

Tags: java, image

I am making a game & trying to add a play button, but it says "The local variable playbutton may not have been initialized,". Here is my code:

```
class graphics extends JPanel{

ImageIcon playbutton = new ImageIcon("res\\playbutton");

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Image playbutton;
    g.drawImage(playbutton, 250, 300, null);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Because the copmpiler is almost always right. In this case, your local declaration of `Image playbutton` **is** never initialized. It's a different variable than the one you have before the method, and declaring it locally hides the first (global) one of the same name.

Comment: Okay, but how am I suppose to fix it exactly?

Comment: As I don't know what it is you're trying to accomplish, it's pretty difficult to tell you exactly how to fix it (which is why I didn't try). Either remove the local variable declaration, and access the outer one instead, or initialize the local one before you try to use it. I'm suspecting you want to do the first, which simply means deleting the `Image playbutton` from within your `paintComponent` method.